# Is an English "uppercase letters puzzle" possible in the Japanese language?

Tags: translation, english-to-japanese

I was playing a game that the main character reads mails that have some uppercase letters in the middle of words. These uppercase letters by the end of a mail will form a number spelled out.

See a toy example below spelling out the number 3:

> Stack Exchange is a ne**T**work of question-and-answer websites on
> topics in diverse fields, eac**H** site covering a specific topic,
> whe**R**e questions, answ**E**rs, and users are subject to a
> r**E**putation award process.

I don't know a thing about the Japanese language and I was wondering: if this game were to be translated to Japanese, is it possible for translators to translate this puzzle to Japanese without having to change the whole dynamic of the puzzle? If it is possible, please show me how one would approach the translation process.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Japanese happens to have two sets of characters for representing the sounds of the language that could be used the same way. These are called hiragana and katakana.

For instance here are 5 of the sounds in the language, in romaji, hiragana, and katakana

a - あ ア
i - い イ
u - う ウ
e - え エ
o - お オ

So you could easily create a message where everything was written in hiragana except for the message you wanted to "hide" dispersed as katakana.